# I am getting an unexpected output of SimpleDateFormat.parse().

Tags: java, simpledateformat

When I am executing the following code

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");

    Date today=new Date();

    String olddate="03/11/2016";
    System.out.println(sdf.parse(olddate));
```

Why the Result is displaying Sun Dec 27 00:00:00 IST 2015.

However I was expecting Wed Nov 03 00:00:00 IST 2016.

Anyone can please explain. And how can I get the desired output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Date format is wrong. It should be y instead of Y-

> dd/MM/yyyy

- Y specify Week year
- y specify Year

For a more detailed insight view, check the link [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and you'll see the meaning of each character we pass there.

Comment: This is correct answer. Just to add a note; timezone it will default to where you located. If you want to set timezone programmatically then SimpleDateFormat sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

Comment: yap, `Date` class considered default timezone, would vary.